# How to print out elements of tuple one per line

Tags: python, output, tuples

Below is my code for a DNA string neighboring question:

```
chars = "ACGT"

def neighbors(pattern, d):
    assert(d <= len(pattern))

    if d == 0:
        return [pattern]

    r2 = neighbors(pattern[1:], d-1)
    r = [c + r3 for r3 in r2 for c in chars if c != pattern[0]]

    if (d < len(pattern)):
        r2 = neighbors(pattern[1:], d)
        r += [pattern[0] + r3 for r3 in r2]

    return r
def neighbors2(pattern, d):
    return ([neighbors(pattern, d2) for d2 in range(d + 1)], [])

print (neighbors2("ACG", 1))
```

The output is below:

```
([['ACG'], ['CCG', 'GCG', 'TCG', 'AAG', 'AGG', 'ATG', 'ACA', 'ACC', 'ACT']], [])
```

How can I add some codes and change the output looking like this kind of pattern:

```
CCG
TCG
GCG
AAG
ATG
AGG
ACA
ACC
ACT
ACG
```

Comment: Your output's order is different than printed one.(ACG printed last, there is an extra AGG, TCG and GCG swapped) Is there any pattern on changes or just typo?

Answer (score 3):

You can use flatten function from compiler.ast module

```
from compiler.ast import flatten
print flatten(neighbors2("ACG", 1))
```

will produce

```
['ACG', 'CCG', 'GCG', 'TCG', 'AAG', 'AGG', 'ATG', 'ACA', 'ACC', 'ACT']
```

or

```
print("\n".join(flatten(neighbors2("ACG", 1))))
```

to have output like this:

```
ACG
CCG
GCG
TCG
AAG
AGG
ATG
ACA
ACC
ACT
```

Comment: the compiler module is Deprecated since version 2.6 and removed in python 3

Comment: @Copperfield too bad :(

Answer (score 2):

there are several way of doing this, you can print each one, make a big string and print it, use the `sep` argument of the print function, make a class that represent your stuff a defined a `__str__` method that return a string the way you want it.

for example

```
>>> test=['CCG', 'GCG', 'TCG', 'AAG', 'AGG', 'ATG', 'ACA', 'ACC', 'ACT']
```

print each one

```
>>> for x in test:
        print(x)


CCG
GCG
TCG
AAG
AGG
ATG
ACA
ACC
ACT
```

make a big string

```
>>> print( "\n".join(test) )
CCG
GCG
TCG
AAG
AGG
ATG
ACA
ACC
ACT
```

using sep and unpacking

```
>>> print( *test, sep="\n" )
CCG
GCG
TCG
AAG
AGG
ATG
ACA
ACC
ACT
```

using a class

```
>>> class Foo:
    def __init__(self,data):
        self.data=data
    def __str__(self):
        return "\n".join(self.data)


>>> x=Foo(test)
>>> print(x)
CCG
GCG
TCG
AAG
AGG
ATG
ACA
ACC
ACT
```

to get from `([['ACG'], ['CCG', 'GCG', 'TCG', 'AAG', 'AGG', 'ATG', 'ACA', 'ACC', 'ACT']], [])` to `['ACG', 'CCG', 'GCG', 'TCG', 'AAG', 'AGG', 'ATG', 'ACA', 'ACC', 'ACT']` you can use the answer to this [Flatten (an irregular) list of lists in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2158395/flatten-an-irregular-list-of-lists-in-python), for example the answer of *unutbu* is the one I like the most

```
from itertools import chain
from collections import Iterable

try: #python 2
    _basestring = basestring
except NameError:
    #python 3
    _basestring = (str,bytes)

def flatten_total(iterable, flattype=Iterable, ignoretype=_basestring):
    """Flatten all level of nesting of a arbitrary iterable"""
    #https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2158395/flatten-an-irregular-list-of-lists-in-python
    #unutbu version
    remanente = iter(iterable)
    while True:
        elem = next(remanente)
        if isinstance(elem,flattype) and not isinstance(elem,ignoretype):
            remanente = chain( elem, remanente )
        else:
            yield elem
```

and do

```
print( "\n".join(flatten_total( neighbors2("ACG", 1))) )
```

Comment: Great answer with lots of different ways. Should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

I you just want to print and the nesting level is always the same, you can do:

```
for entry in neighbors2("ACG", 1)[0]:
    print(*entry, sep='\n')
```

Output:

```
ACG
CCG
GCG
TCG
AAG
AGG
ATG
ACA
ACC
ACT
```